# Joining more than one Column between mapped Entities

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Spring + MySQL

Entities Audit and Enterprise are mapped by relation @ManyToOne by their Id's (int).
In my aplication I want to filter Audits by Enterprise's name. Both respectively have service, ad DAO classes. Since I have query for filtering Enterprises by name:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Enterprise e WHERE e.name LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')")
List<Enterprise> findByName(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm);
```

I thought that the simplest way would be to add column to Audit class that contains Enterprise's name, and do similar thing.
Is there a way to do this type of doble mapping, or way to automatically generate this column?
Or maybe the whole concept is just wrong, and I should do this other way round?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTERPRISES")
public class Enterprise {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    int enterpriseId;

    @Column
    String name;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Audit.class,
            mappedBy = "enterprise",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    List<Audit> audits = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Audit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    public int auditId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTERPRISE_ID")
    public Enterprise enterprise;

}
```

Since the question is half technical half theoretical, and I'm new to programming in general I didn't try to do much in this matter. I was wondering that maybe @Generated() annotation would work with @Column(columnDefinition = ... ), but still I don't know how to define this column.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are after; I hope it isn't putting enterprise 'data' into the Audit entity/table. You can filter audits on what ever you want in queries: "select a from Audit a join a.enterprise e where e.name LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchTerm, '%')".

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I'm just bad ad queries,a and hadn't came across this pattern